# How can I prove that $\sum x_n$ converges if and only if $\sum y_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Say that there are two series: $\sum x_n$ and $\sum y_n$ where there is N such that $x_n = y_n$ for all $n > N$. How can I prove that if one converges if and only if the other does? Using the Cauchy criterion is given as a hint but I am having problems how that can be applied to this scenario.

Comment: $\sum x_{n} - \sum y_{n}$ is finite since one can subtract the infinite tails where each resulting term is $0$. If $\sum x_{n} $converges...?

Comment: So the tail end of their difference is less than epsilon, that proves their difference is Cauchy. But how does that prove the statement?

Comment: $x_{n}-y_{n} = 0$ for all $n > N$. Then we have $(x_{1}-y_{1})+...+(x_{N}-y_{N})$, i.e. a sum of a finite number of terms, which is itself finite. Hence, $\sum x_{n}-\sum y_{n} = C$ for some real number $C$, and if one of these converges what does that mean for the other?

Comment: Oh yes I get it now. The other would also have to converge since it wouldn't make sense if it diverged but still somehow had their difference be equal to a real number.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Thank you for walking me through!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for all $n > N$,
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_j - \sum_{j = 1}^{n}y_j = \sum_{j = 1}^{N}(x_j - y_j)$$
is constant. Let's call this constant $C$. Then for $n > N$,
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_j = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}y_j + C,$$
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n}y_j = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_j - C.$$
The first equation shows that if $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}y_j \to S$ as $n \to \infty$, then $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_j \to S + C$ as $n \to \infty$. The second equation shows that if $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_j \to S$ as $n \to \infty$, then $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}y_j \to S - C$.

Comment: This is just what I commented but with less explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I think I am starting to get it now with your comment along with Derek Luna's!

Comment: @DerekLuna You can't do $\sum x_n - \sum y_n$ since $\sum x_n - \sum y_n$ only makes sense when both $\sum x_n$ and $\sum y_n$ converge. You have to work with partial sums.

Comment: You did exactly that when you said Let's call this constant $C$ and then just rearranged it...